# How make an image pop up in a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hey everyone I'm trying to make an img pop up in a modal when an img is clicked. When the img is  clicked I put the src in a variable and then add that src to an img with a blank src in my modal. For some reason the modal isn't popping up. Can you check my code and see what's wrong?

THANK YOU!!! I've been stumped for so long.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.imggallery2').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        variableWidth: true,
        centerMode: true,
        nextArrow: "<span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'>",
        prevArrow: "<span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left'>",
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
    
   $("img").click(function(){
       var sr=$(this).attr('src');
       $('#mimg').attr('src',sr);
       $("#myModal").modal(); 
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blackpropixfallen.css">
<!-- Satisfy Google Font -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Slick Carousel -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class = "reveal">
                    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                    <img  src="" id = "mimg" class = "modalimg" width = "280px" height = "280px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class = "imggallery2">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/IMG_4553.jpg">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/Interconnected.jpg">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/LifeLongLies pt.2 (yellow).jpg">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/Mornin' Murderin' Marauder (abstract).jpg">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/Mornin' Murderin' Marauder (Red).jpg">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/Nightfall (vibrant).jpg">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/Paris 15.jpg">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/Paris 18.jpg">
        <img src = "Fallengallery/Somebody's Watching.jpg">
    </div>
                
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It will be easier for us to debug if you post the code as a runnable snippet (use the `<>`button on the toolbar).

Comment: It is actually working in your snippet. And it does change the url href of the modal img based on the clicked image, your modal does appear too in your snippet

Comment: @masterpreenz i see in the console it has the img src but the modal itself isn't popping up...is there any reason this would happen?

Comment: no `.modal()` is undefined error in your console?

Comment: @masterpreenz yes it says Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (blackpropixfallen.html?_c9_id=livepreview3&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io:78)
    at HTMLImageElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLImageElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3)

Comment: That means your `modal` library has failed to load, probably that `bootstrap.min.js <script>`

Comment: i figured it out @masterpreenz thank you for working wit me...those extra scripts i have at the bottom aren't needed